# Read raw resource from library project using Context.createPackageContext()

Tags: android, android-resources

I'm sharing resources between projects via a library project. Here's the structure :

```
MyLibProject
`-- res
   `-- raw
      `-- my_shared_res
`-- AndroidManifest.xml
   `-- Shared user id -> my.shared.user.id
   `-- Package        -> some.package


MyProject
`-- AndroidManifest.xml
   `-- Shared user id -> my.shared.user.id
   `-- Package        -> some.other.package
```

Inside the `Activity` of `MyProject` I want to access `R.raw.My_shared_res`, but then I noticed the following :

- `getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.my_shared_res)` -> returns the correct content of the file while
- `Context c = createPackageContext("some.package", Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE & Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY); c.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.my_shared_res);` -> returns a different content, I presumed ciphered.

Can someone explain why this happens ?

**Edit :** I've posted the question on Android Developers google group. You can see responses by following this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/android-developers/createPackageContext%2420ciphered%2420content/android-developers/uKdj70B3cYk/nGGDMrwRSrMJ) too

Comment: Btw. flags should be ORed not ANDed, so use `|`.